# Converting DateTime GMT to Local Time

Tags: email, html, activities

I have a Date/Time field that is used for Activities (events) that shows up in an HTML generated email when an Event is created. My issue is that the time shows in GMT timezone format instead of the Users local timezone.

Is there any way to write a formula to change the timezone of this field from GMT to local time, or Eastern Daylight time?

Comment: I think you'd need a `Visualforce Template` where you could use `Apex` to query the user record and calculate the offset.

Comment: Are you suggesting subtracting the hour so that it shows the difference (15:00 ->11:00AM)? 
@AdrianLarson My only concern with this is that come November(?) DST ends making that change obsolete. I would like to figure out if it is possible to just format it not as the SFDC default GMT :/

Comment: As long as you use `Apex` that's no issue. The `Timezone` class has a `getOffset` method.